# Is it possible to modify the type name in a query graphql

Tags: c#, .net, types, graphql, hotchocolate

I explain my situation :)

A server/client is sending me this query :

```
query MultiTenancy__GraphQLAPI__FindMatchesQuery($name: String!, $email: String!, $registrationNumbers: [RegistrationNumberAttributes!]!, $phoneNumber: String,
 $birthDate: ISO8601Date) {
  collaboratorMatches(name: $name, email: $email, nationalRegistrationNumbers: $registrationNumbers, phoneNumber: $phoneNumber, birthDate: $birthDate) {
    canCreate
    matches {
      id
      name ...
  }
}
```

But, my graphql server doesn't recognize the query.

[my query error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azfey.png)

On my side, when I send the same request in local with playground or Altair, to make it work, I have to change $registrationNumbers Type and $birthDate Type like this :

```
query MultiTenancy__GraphQLAPI__FindMatchesQuery($name: String!, $email: String!, $registrationNumbers: [RegistrationNumberInput!]!, 
  $phoneNumber: String,$birthDate: DateTime!)
```

Do you know how I can replace these input type names? Or if there is another solution? Or if I can create my own scalar type ISO8601Date to understand the query I receive?

Thx all :)

Comment: you have to use server/API defined input types - read from API docs/specs